# How we can use dynamic android modules in local android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-app-bundle

it is possible to use dynamic modules in custom android application ? without using android store. The application is a local application with differents features.

Comment: Why you involve android store? To grab modules? Can't you take the aar libs for desired modules?

Comment: my main goal is to use dynamic features for my  app. It is a local app and I will not publish it in google store. I have found this class SplitInstallRequest to install dynamic modules. It is work in debug mode but I'm not sure if it will be work for release mode.

Comment: build an unsigned release apk and run it. If it works, great, will work.

Comment: I have create a signed apk then when I click to download feature, it is not working ... I don't know if there is a solution to download modules without google store...

Comment: No.. is their own store feature..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SplitInstallManager` is part of Google Play API, I'm afraid you can't walk-around this since they don't allow any 3rd party source of modules. Instead, you can do your own API if you really want to.